# FTGL alternative

Tags: library, c, opengl, freetype

I need to display TrueType fonts in OpenGL, in a C program. This needs to work on fairly old hardware, so something using the old fixed function pipeline rather than making heavy use of shaders would be good. Can someone suggest a good alternative to [FTGL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/)?

Reasons FTGL doesn't quite work for me:

- The C API leaves out an important feature of the C++ API: the ability to get a bounding box for a "partial string" from a layout (it should take a char pointer and a length argument, rather than just taking a char pointer and reading to the first null character).

  I need this feature so I can determine where pointer events fall within a string, because I need to implement caret insertion and text selection capability.
- The font rendering doesn't look as nice as more modern techniques, like the technique discussed at http://contourtextures.wikidot.com/.

  I can live without this rendering technique, but it would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [freetype-gl](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/) for now. It uses contour textures, they look great. It also uses shaders, but they seem to work alright on the hardware I tested on. It's pretty rough around the edges but I think it will handle my use cases.

Answer (score 0):

[stb_truetype](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h) by Sean Barrett is a Public Domain true type implementation in a single C (or C++) header.

There is some design information about it [here](http://nothings.org/gamedev/font_rendering_malloc.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but have a look at [glyphy](https://github.com/behdad/glyphy):

> GLyphy is a signed-distance-field (SDF) text renderer using OpenGL ES2 shading language.